# Do you use joists sistered to rim boards?

Tags: framing

When running floor joist packages, do you run your starting joist 16" on center from the outside of the rimboard, or do you put rimboard and a joist at the very beginning?

Comment: Depends on what type of joists we're talking about. Most engineering spec packages will make that clear.

Comment: Being more specific like I am building a deck, a shed  or ? Would help the context. When I use TJI I put the rim board up last.

Comment: @isherwood, does it matter what kind of joists?  I-joists you'll still use dimensional or maybe an lvl for the rim joist and then the spacing should just be 16" oc from that starter to support the floor load above.  Dimensional I think would follow same pattern.

Comment: Is this engineered framing as in "I" joists, and OSB rim board or dimensional lumber as in solid, one piece cut from a tree and dried?

Answer (score 1):

"Rimboard" is a somewhat unusual term for what is usually (in the US, at least) called a "rim joist". Since there's already a joist at the outside edge, and it's usually supported directly on the foundation (or piers or whatever foundation system you're using), there's *usually** no need to sister it up.

*Note: If you have an unusually long span, are cantilevering joists of the outside of the rim, or have some other, unusual situation, there may be cause for sistering the rim joist.